# On debian, removing one virtual interface eth0:0 removes other virtual interfaces. Why?

Tags: networking, debian, virtualization

Tried searching for the answer a lot of times. I have two virtual interfaces eth0:0(10.0.0.1) and eth0:1(10.0.0.2). I am trying to remove only eth0:0 interface. If I execute the command "ifconfig eth0:0 down", eth0:1 also gets removed. However if they are in different networks say eth0:1 has 11.0.0.1, eth0:1 stays put. Why is this behavior?

Comment: I think I stumped over that on some really old debian but did not investigate. You can just not use eth0:0 and start you ip aliases from eth0:1

Comment: Don't use old-style aliases anymore.

Comment: I specifically wanted eth0:0 to be removed in the scripts. That interface is being used all over the place in the scripts